# Showing error message Grails - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

From my grails Controller class i need to show an error message from the GSP file.

```
def myControllerMethod() {

    if (fruit==apple){
       // Do something
    } else {
       Show the error message, from the GSP file. 
    }

}
```

In the GSP file. I have the following code which is the error message i want to **show for 5 seconds** and then it should disappear.

```
<body>
...
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <a href="#" class="alert-link">...</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Javascript / JQuery for that. Below an example:

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    $('div.alert').fadeOut("slow"); }, 
5000 );
```

More information with setTimeout [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

You can also use delay() (more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/))

Example:

```
def myController() {
    def message
    if (fruit==apple){
       // Do something
    } else {
       message = 'Your message' 
    }
    return [message:message, ...]
}
```

In your view:

```
<g:if test="${ message }">
 ...
</g:if>
```

And don't forget to enable alert:

```
$(".alert").alert()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My main problem is how do i call that DIV from the Grails Controller?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Tell me if it is what you need

Comment: Where should i add `$(".alert").alert()` this?

Comment: In a JS file (or inside <r:script></r:script> if you have resources plugin). Usually, at the end of your layout (after jquery.js and bootstrap.js)

Comment: Why are you recommending that he use flash?  It could work but is kind of a peculiar use of flash which is usually used to hold on to data during a redirect.

Comment: @Jeff Scott Brown: Thanks for the comment. I read again the documentation about flash scope and it is not what I thought.